# Creating buttons dynamically with different functions in python/kivy

Tags: python, kivy, parameter-passing, kivy-language

I'm struggling a little with a program that is supposed to read a text document and use it to create a variable number of kivy buttons, based on its content. The text file in this example would be 4 lines of which the first is text1, the sendond argument1 and than text2 and argument2.

```
f = open("text.txt", "r")
line = f.readlines()
i=0
while (i !=4): 
    self.managerself.manager.get_screen("Screen1").ids.name.add_widget(Button(text = line[i], on_press =lambda x:self.callback(line[i]+1)))
    i=i+2
```

my code creates two buttons labeled text1 and text2, but passes argument2 for both. Is it possible to get it to use the '  line[i]+1  ' value of the time of its creation? I hope thats not a stupid question..Thank you in advance!!

Comment: This is a Python gotcha, [late-binding closures](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures), not anything to do with kivy in particular. The link there also explains how to avoid the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand the Problem now, still not sure what the default arg exactly does, but I got my code to working how i imagined! :)